# add a new route to controller from within controller?

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core

- Let's say I have a CMS in ASP.NET Core.
- Let's say the root URL is `test.net`.
- Let's say I add the new page `test.net/docs/doc1.html` as an administrative user.

As soon as the API call to update my database completes I want to be able to navigate to this URL and this URL routed to let's say `Content` controller.

How to properly configure "catch all" controller, I mean controller which gets the path from URL and fetches the page from the database? My goal is to allow any path to be handled. No fixed paths, if DB says there's some content at `1/2/3/4/5.html` I want it handled by `Content` controller.

It's however important the MVC must still work here. So I have my fixed routes to API, but non-API URL-s are to be caught and handled by one common `Content` controller.

Comment: @MickyD 1. Read all about routing in ASP.NET Core. Build a custom router. I managed to create static routes. IDK how to add a route after the app has been started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can all your content be in one folder, e.g. Content? In that case you can use Catch All (wildcard) route approach from within Content controller:

```
public class Content : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    [Route("/Content/{*catchall}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string catchall)
    {
        // catchall = 1/2/3/4/5.html    
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Works as charm, I used `[Route("{*catchall}")]` and I don't even need a separate folder. It still matches API calls properly. I wish I knew where those "magic strings" are explained...